# Required Hawk Authentication for a GET API Call in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a one GET API request , need to pass it through JMeter but it requires Hawk Authentication . I have also Hawk Auth ID, Hawk Auth Key , Algorithm values.

In postman it works fine but when convert that postman script into JMeter script and execute, it gives an error message like "Unauthorized" & response code - 401 .

So I need to know the configuration process of Hawk authentication in JMeter.

Can anyone please help me regarding that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out  [Hawk Java API implementation](https://github.com/wealdtech/hawk), example code can be found in the

Example code with explanation is provided in the [Building Your Own -> Clients](http://wealdtech.github.io/hawk/core.html) documentation chapter, just in case I'll  replicate the code snippet here:

```
import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkClient
import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials
import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials.Algorithm

//If you want your clients to authenticate using Hawk then you will need to start with a set of Hawk credentials:

HawkCredentials hawkCredentials = new HawkCredentials.Builder()
                                                     .keyId("dh37fgj492je")
                                                     .key("werxhqb98rpaxn39848xrunpaw3489ruxnpa98w4rxn")
                                                     .algorithm(Algorithm.SHA256)
                                                     .build();

//Once these have been configuration you can create a Hawk client:

HawkClient hawkClient = new HawkClient.Builder().credentials(hawkCredentials).build();

//And then for each request that you wish to send you need to generate an authorization header:

String authorizationHeader = hawkClient.generateAuthorizationHeader(uri, method, body, ext);

//This string needs to be added to the outgoing HTTP request as the content of the "Authorization" header. 

//and JMeter specifics:

vars.put('authorizationHeader', authorizationHeader)
```

This code you need to put into the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

After that add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `${authorizationHeader}`

Comment: Hi @Dmitri thanks for your answer but above code not working properly. When I executed the code ,it gives an error  like  " javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: uri for class: Script63 " . Please let me know if you have any suggestion regarding that . #Jmeter

Comment: It's **you** who need to pass the `uri` to the function, you can get it in JSR223 PreProcessor as `sampler.getUrl().toURI()` where `sampler` stands for [HTTPSamplerBase](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html), see the JavaDoc for more information on all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more details on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands